# Vertical and Horizontal centering a div inside another

Tags: html, css, position, centering

I am trying to center a div inside another div.
I have tried the following HTML and CSS

HTML

```
<div class="header">
 <div class="homeImageText">
    <h1>Document Preparation Like Never Before</h1>
    </div><!--homeImagetext end-->
</div>
```

CSS

```
.homeImageText {
left:0; right:0;
top:0; bottom:0;
margin:auto;
max-width:100%;
max-height:100%;
}

header{
background: url(../images/header1.png) center center no-repeat; ;
height: 600px;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```

[Live](http://types4u.org/vert/)
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sa3Mk/)

Comment: add `position: absolute` to `.homeImageText` and `position: relative` to `header`

Comment: @Mathias That did not solve the issue I have.

Comment: Note that this doesnt center the div itself, it makes it the same size as the parent

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's The Best Way of Centering a Div Vertically with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/whats-the-best-way-of-centering-a-div-vertically-with-css)

Comment: [How's this?](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/sa3Mk/3/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/sa3Mk/2/)

For vertical centering, make the wrapping `div` set to `display-table` and the child to `display:table-cell` with `vertical-align:middle`. Horizontal centering can then simply be accomplished with `text-align:center;`

Try the CSS:

```
.header {
    height: 600px;
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
.homeImageText {
    height:100%;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
}
```